# Stacked bar chart transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get the bar transition one by one in the horizontal stacked bar chart. But each bar is starting at the same time.

```
rects = groups.selectAll('stackedBar')
  .data(function(d,i) {
    console.log("data", d, i);
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
    .attr('class','stackedBar')
    .attr('x', function(d) { return xScale(d.x0); })
    .attr('y', function(d, i) {return yScale(d.y); })
    .attr('height', function(d) { return yScale.rangeBand(); })
    .attr('width', 0)
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d, i){
        console.log('hi', d, i);
        return i * 500;
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.x0); })
      .duration(1000);
```

How can i make it animate one by one? Thanks!

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PreethiRS/dBpv3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there -- you need to use `.delay()` to achieve this, as you're doing already. The only problem is that you're using a nested selection (i.e. `rect`s within `g`s) and the index you get is that of the inner selection. This is always 0 because there's only one `rect` per `g`.

To make it work, reference the secret third argument in a nested selection, which is the index within the data passed to the parent:

```
.delay(function(d,i,j){console.log('hi',d,j); return j*500;})
```

This will give you the index of the `g` element. Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dBpv3/2/).